# GCM for iOS push notifications with error : com.google.iid error 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I got below issues while registering to the app with GCM for iOS push notifications:

Registration to GCM failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 0.)
Could not connect to GCM: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.gcm error 501.)

Can I use GCM for iOS push notifications?
Please help me with the above, quick solutions would be appreciable!!!
Thank you!!!

Comment: Did you google this ? First link in google results https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in founding a solution long back ago, the above error (com.google.iid error 0 or 501) indicates passing wrong parameters or null parameters.Check error codes for GCM.

Comment: Can you show what you did to resolve this? I receive error 0

Comment: Could you please add the link to an official source for these error codes?